# How to install gRPC properly?

Tags: php, github, installation, grpc, google-ads-api

Good days, I am trying to install the library with the "pecl install grpc" command and it is returning the following error: "Fatal error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in C:\xampp\php\pear\PEAR\Config.php on line 2095".

I don't know why but it gives a PHP related syntax error.

The PHP version I'm using is:

"PHP 8.2.0 (cli) (built: Dec 6 2022 15:31:23) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies"

And it is not only that file but many more with which it gives a syntax error.

Tried reinstalling PHP and Xampp

Any solution or idea on how to fix it or install it properly?

Thank you.

Comment: On Windows, the source grpc-1.52.0.tgz needs to be compiled into a .dll first.

Answer (score 1):

for php 8.2 in windows, I suggest search dll extension that are available on this forum https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=42043 . just search for grpc and there will be zip for it along with other dll/extension. If you just need grpc, only extract php_grpc.dll in ext folder that are on zip. then copy paste it into yours ext folder of php, usually in /xampp/ext/php/ext if you're using xampp. also edit yours php.ini and added `extension=grpc`.